# mouseover map region to display image and mouseout to hide

Tags: javascript, html

I've an Europe map. When i mouse-over Italy region, i wish to display the map image and disappear when mouse-out. However, i cant make it works perfectly.

Below is the HTML

```js
function show(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

function hide(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#map01 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 334px;
  top: 562px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img id="map01" src="images/italy.png" />
<img src="images/map.jpg" width="1000" height="816" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="poly" onMouseOver="show('map01')" onMouseOut="hide('map01')" coords="339,597,334,598,338,604,335,613,345,617,346,622,353,622,357,615,366,612,378,618,382,622,387,636,394,647,406,657,421,670,427,676,438,676,441,679,450,684,456,689,457,695,467,696,472,701,475,712,478,719,474,725,474,737,478,737,486,726,486,716,492,715,491,709,485,703,480,698,484,689,489,684,496,689,503,688,504,694,510,695,509,688,502,682,490,676,482,672,472,670,468,665,473,662,460,659,449,658,441,648,438,640,432,630,422,622,416,615,410,606,414,599,410,592,419,589,428,586,428,577,428,572,415,570,411,563,402,561,393,565,386,566,385,575,376,573,369,581,366,585,361,579,357,574,353,584,344,584,338,584,340,595" href="#" />
    </map>
```

Here's my code
http://codepen.io/w3nta1/pen/JWrmaz

Comment: You should avoid using image maps if possible, they are more difficult for Google to index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Changed the answer.

After tinkering a bit I realized that the problem is that the image overlays the map. The solution was to move the use map on to the italy image and switch to `opacity` instead of `display`.

the code became a follows:

**Please note that I eyeballed the area approximately.**

```js
function show(id) {
     document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = 1;
   }
   function hide(id) {
     document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = 0;
   }
```

```css
#map01  {  position: absolute; left:342px; top:569px; opacity:0; }
```

```html
<map name="Map" id="Map">
 <area onMouseOver="show('map01')" onMouseOut="hide('map01')" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="56,78,65,87,74,94,82,97,93,105,100,111,131,134,140,143,143,161,136,170,120,174,99,175,88,177,92,188,127,199,132,194,133,181,149,174,156,154,158,148,150,138,151,126,174,135,176,126,140,108,138,101,101,77,82,54,77,32,98,24,94,8,74,0,66,0,54,7,39,12,32,22,25,12,19,20,7,22,7,31,2,37,6,46,4,54,13,63,30,50,47,56,39,115,32,118,21,123,26,139,27,159,38,156,42,128,40,120,50,65,47,58,48,60" />
</map>
<img id="map01" src="https://image.ibb.co/bYLutv/italy.png" usemap="#Map"/>
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/hEbZtv/map.jpg" width="1000" height="816"  border="0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but the mouseover region become rectangular instead of area shape. This will have problem if mouseover other countries later coz the rectangular will overlap :(

Comment: @clement - Changed my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @MaksymStepanenko .It works like a charm. Previously i don't have any idea how to solve and it took me very long to think of it. Thanks for your solution, it helps me a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpZYeX) seems to fix the issue.

I took the listeners out of the html and put them into your javascript area.  I also used `onmouseenter` and `onmouseexit` instead of `onmousein` and `onmouseout` though I'm not totally sure this was a necesary change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version : https://codepen.io/jonathanmarotta/pen/poarREK

(credits to Bango in his previous answer ...)

```
document.getElementById('poly').onmouseleave = function() {
hide('map01');
};
```

(Note : to generate the area(s) you need in your image, you can use any map generator like this online one for example : https://www.image-map.net/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).